# How to Add record in sunspot "search.results"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I detect N + 1 in my project.

i have this two models

```
class Person
  has_one :profile
  delegate :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :full_name, to: :profile

  searchable do
    text :first_name, stored: true
    text :middle_name, stored: true
    text :last_name, stored: true
    text :full_name, stored: true
  end
end

class Profile
   delegate :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :full_name, to: :profile

   def full_name
     #some code that will output full name
   end
end
```

this is my controller for Person

```
def index
  args = search_params
  search = person_search(args)
  @persons = search.results

end


def persons_search(args)
  fulltext_fields = %i[first_name last_name full_name].freeze

  Person.search do
   if params.key?(:q)
     fulltext params[:q], fields: fulltext_fields, query_phrase_slop: 0, minimum_match: 2 do
     fulltext_fields.each { |field| highlight field, max_snippets: 3, fragment_size: 100 }
    end
   end

fulltext_fields.each do |field|
  fulltext params[field], fields: field, query_phrase_slop: 0, minimum_match: 3 if params.key?(field)
end


 end

end
```

Okay now i explain the back end now lets go to the HTML

hers my table

```
 tbody
  - @members.each do |member|
   tr
    td.p-2 = member.reference_number
    td.p-2 = member.first_name <----------- THIS IS THE N + 1
```

as you can see in my table i repeat to call the "first_name"(I have 5k record) my conclusion is to add the "first_name" in the search result so i dont call the association profile?

is this the proper way to do it???
any suggestion is open :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Person.search(include: [:profile]) do
   if params.key?(:q)
     fulltext params[:q], fields: fulltext_fields, query_phrase_slop: 0, minimum_match: 2 do
     fulltext_fields.each { |field| highlight field, max_snippets: 3, fragment_size: 100 }
    end
   end
```

in my understanding. i put include in search so the sunspot include the association. i use the bullet gem. thats why im come up in this problem.

i think my table render the search result association. not the rails association. feel free to comment. if my explanation is not correct. im also a noob thanks :)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase sure bro ill try my best to explain